# Tableau CRM Dashboard Packaging with AppExchange Apps

Tags: managed-package, einstein-analytics, licenses, 2gp, tableau

We are working on an AppExchange App which will be an ISV app and not the OEM application.
Currently there are few standard reports and dashboards are part of package which can be used by customers without any customization.

As an enhancements, we would like to provide **Tableau (Einstein Analytics) Dashboards** as part of the package.

But considering dependency on  "Tableau (Einstein Analytics)" feature, we are not sure if any customers who don't have "Tableau (Einstein Analytics) CRM" enabled on their machine can install our package? So, we are planning to create a separate add-on 2GP package which can be installable on the customer orgs who has Tableau (Einstein Analytics) CRM licenses available.

**Question:** Can someone please confirm, is this (separate add-on 2GP package - only for TCRM dashboards) the correct way to deliver "Tableau (Einstein Analytics) Dashboards package" for the an AppExchange application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2GP package approach is a valid way to deliver tableaucrm assets, and other ISVs do it this way currently.

I believe you should be able to deploy the package with the tcrm dashboards but wouldn’t be able to see or use them without tableau CRM licenses. This might require that the dashboards be in an [analytics app template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_wave_templates.meta/bi_dev_guide_wave_templates/bi_templatesdev_intro_wave_templates.htm) in the package, which is the recommended approach anyways.

You could also look into using the 'Analytics View Only Embedded App license' for the users that will only be viewing the dashboards, assuming you’re going to embed the dashboards in a lightning page and not need studio access.

Check out Embedded app template [limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_wave_templates.meta/bi_dev_guide_wave_templates/bi_templatesdev_app_type.htm). I believe any type of analytics asset is supported, including recipes. Additionally, since embedded apps don’t show in Analytics Studio nor can View Only Embedded App users get to Studio, you need to expose the app assets elsewhere (e.g. in a Lightning page, or aura, or LWC component).

Note:These are the few inputs I've got upon reaching out internally to our experts team.I will update the thread when I have more info on limitations of Embedded App license

Comment: Thanks a lot Swetha for the detailed explanation.  I know Embedded App license works with OEM applications.  But I am not sure if Embedded App licenses can be used ISVForce (non-OEM) apps?